# Requesting data with Chainlink, response not what expected

Tags: solidity, web3js, hardhat, chainlink

I've been trying to integrate Chainlink into my contract, managed to get the random number thingy working, but the API call doesn't work for me. Here's what I got:

```
contract ValorantCards is Ownable, ERC1155, VRFConsumerBase, ChainlinkClient {
using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

address private linkToken;

// Chainlink VRF
bytes32 private keyHash;
uint256 private vrfFee;

uint256 public randomResult;

// Chainlink API calls
address private oracle;
bytes32 private jobId;
uint256 private oracleFee;

uint256 public playerLevel;

constructor(
    address _vrfCoordinator,
    address _linkToken,
    bytes32 _keyHash,
    address _oracle,
    bytes32 _jobId,
    uint256 _oracleFee
) ERC1155("") VRFConsumerBase(_vrfCoordinator, _linkToken) {
    setPublicChainlinkToken();

    linkToken = _linkToken;
    keyHash = _keyHash;
    vrfFee = 0.1 * 10**18;

    oracle = _oracle;
    jobId = _jobId;
    oracleFee = _oracleFee;
}

function requestUserLevel() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
    Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(
        jobId,
        address(this),
        this.fulfill.selector
    );

    request.add(
        "get",
        "https://api.henrikdev.xyz/valorant/v1/account/draven/2023"
    );
    request.add("path", "data.account_level");

    return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, oracleFee);
}

function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _level)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
{
    playerLevel = _level;
}
```

I'm deploying from hardhat, with the following parameters (ignoring the ones for VRF since that's working):

Oracle: 0x9C0383DE842A3A0f403b0021F6F85756524d5599

JobId: 0x3766623533366265383635623433333662323766633130313437633139336337

OracleFee: 0.1 * 10**18

The function runs fine, the transaction doesn't revert or anything, but when I check "playerLevel", it's always just 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Etherscan activity, it looks like the node you are using may be inactive. Try this node and jobId:

```
Oracle = 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8; 
JobId = "d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747";
```

These were taken from the [Chainlink Official Docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/decentralized-oracles-ethereum-mainnet/).

To check to see if a node may be inactive or not, check out the oracle address in a block explorer. [You can see here](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x9C0383DE842A3A0f403b0021F6F85756524d5599) that the original node you tried to use hasn't posted a transaction in awhile.

If a node is inactive you will need to find a new one or host one yourself. To find more nodes and jobs, you can check [market.link](https://market.link/) or use the one found in the docs as mentioned earlier.